# Serial data over UART gets corrupted

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, uart, termios

I'm developing an application for a development board (Beagle Bone Black) that will send some data over `UART` peripheral. The developing board runs `Linux Kernel` (some Debian distribution, `3.8.x` Linux Kernel version).

For sending and receiving data over `UART` I use the standard `UNIX` API: `open()`, `read()`, and `write()` family functions.

For setting the communication parameters (`baud rate`, `stop/start bits`, `parity`, etc...) I use the `termios` structure (from `termios.h`).

This is some relevant code sequence where I make the I/O settings:

```
fd_debug = open("output.out", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

fd_write = open(port.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
std::cout << std::endl << "I opened: " << port;

struct termios settings;
tcgetattr(fd_write, &settings);

cfsetospeed(&settings, B19200);         /* baud rate */
settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;            /* no parity */
settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;            /* 1 stop bit */
settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
settings.c_cflag |= CS8 | CLOCAL;       /* 8 bits */
settings.c_lflag = ICANON;              /* canonical mode */
settings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;             /* raw output */

tcsetattr(fd_write, TCSANOW, &settings); /* apply the settings */
tcflush(fd_write, TCOFLUSH);
```

There I opened two file descriptors:

- `fd_debug`: Linked to a file, for debugging purposes.
- `fd_write`: Linked to the UART peripheral (`/dev/ttyO4` in my particular case).

This is the function that is executed when I want to send one byte over `UART`:

```
int UARTIOHandler::write(uchar8 byte) {
    auto tp = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::endl << "[write] Timestamp: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tp.time_since_epoch()).count();
    ::write(fd_debug, &byte, 1);
    return ::write(this->fd_write, &byte, 1);
}
```

For checking if the data I send is received correctly over `UART`, I have connected the `TX` and `RX` pins (loopback test) on my board (because I want to be able to receive back the data that I send), and run `minicom` on that particular `UART` port:

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyO4 -b 19200 -C test.test
```

After sending some data, I compared the two files (debugging file and the output file generated by `minicom` (which should contain the data received over `UART`)). The problem is that the data is not the same!

This is the actually data sent (in hexadecimal):

```
55 33 02 04 06 08 0a 0c d5 55 0b 01 03 05 07 ef 55 3f 07 06 05 04 03 02 01 e3 55 16 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 db 55 3f 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 e3
```

This is the data received in the debug file (it's the same, so this confirms that there's some `UART` problem):

```
55 33 02 04 06 08 0a 0c d5 55 0b 01 03 05 07 ef 55 3f 07 06 05 04 03 02 01 e3 55 16 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 db 55 3f 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 e3
```

And this is the data received by `minicom` tool (that was set to listen to the same `UART` port, and the same settings (`baud`, `parity`, etc):

```
55 33 02 04 06 08 0a d5 55 01 03 4d 69 6e 69 63 6f 6d 32 2e 36 2e 31 07 ef 55 3f 07 06 4d 69 6e 69 63 6f 6d 32 2e 36 2e 31 04 03 02 01 e3 55 16 01 02 03 04 4d 69 6e 69 63 6f 6d 32 2e 36 2e 31 06 07 08 db 55 3f 01 02 03 04 4d 69 6e 69 63 6f 6d 32 2e 36 2e 31 06 07 e3
```

As can be observed from a point all data gets corrupted, and there's more bytes received.

For checking the actual data from the output files I used `hexdump` like this:

```
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x "' test.test
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: C++ is not C. It helps if you know which programming language you are programming in.

Comment: @Lundin `unistd.h` and `termios.h` are C POSIX library components, this is why I flagged the `C` language.

Comment: Did you check the configuration of minicom, especially the flow control (hardware and software) ?

Comment: @blatinox I have tried every combination (hardware on/off, software on/off) and it didn't affect the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be Minicom responding to the ENQ character (0x05) and recording its response in the session capture. The additional data is `Minicom2.6.1` which is not corruption. It is substituted for every 0x05 in your stream.

Comment: Also seems to have skipped `0c` and `0b`.

Comment: This may be the actually problem, I can actually see the `Minicom2.6.1` strings in the live `minicom` session. I didn't found any way to disable this substitutions tho.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes. They are "vertical tab" and "form feed", minicom is probably acting on them rather than passing them through. In the olden days, a ^L (0x12) in your stream would give you a fresh sheet on your hardcopy terminal. (Also why it's used as the redraw command in things like `vi` and `curses`)